# nanoc does not find my PHP files on autocompile

Tags: nanoc

I'm using [nanoc](http://nanoc.ws) to build a static website which has a PHP script for sending mails. Simplified structure:

```
/content/index.html
/content/contact.html
/content/mail.php
```

However, when I do a `nanoc compile` everything is fine in my output folder:

```
index.html
contact/index.html
mail/index.php
```

But I can't call the PHP script when doing a `nanoc autocompile`. `/contact/` works, but `/mail/` does not.

This is a part of my Rules-file:

```
route '*' do
    if item.binary?
        # Write item with identifier /foo/ to /foo.ext
        original_filename(item)
    else
        # Write item with identifier /foo/ to /foo/index.extension
        item.identifier + "index.#{item[:extension]}"
    end
end
```

PHP is treated as non-binary. Does anyone know how I can get this to work with `autocompile`?

Answer (score 1):

If anybody is having similar problems: I found the [answer](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/nanoc/L2IC6jMavq4/Bp-EHzbsxz4J):

> The autocompiler does not have support for PHP files. If a directory
>   is requested, the autocompiler looks for an index.html file in it, but
>   it will ignore an index.php file. The autocompiler can’t find a MIME
>   type for it, so it sends the file as application/octet-stream back to
>   the browser.

It's pretty obvious, but I did not have in mind that autocompile runs a light-weight server with no PHP support (of course).